# How to align AttributedText ?

Tags: xamarin.ios

I have an UITextView containing attributed text.
I'm trying to center it (because the text is attributed, textView.TextAlignment doesn't work).

How can I do ? 
I tried this :

```
var attributes = new CTStringAttributes() { };
var paragraphStyleSettings = new CTParagraphStyleSettings() { Alignment = CTTextAlignment.Center };
attributes.ParagraphStyle = new CTParagraphStyle(paragraphStyleSettings);
textView.AttributedText = attributedString;
```

But I get the following crash : `Foundation.MonoTouchException - NSInvalidArgumentException [NSCFType textBlocks]: unrecognized selector sent to instance ...`
[image]

So I guess it's not the right way CTParagraphStyleSettings should be used ? But I couldn't find any example of use with Xamarin syntax... How can I set my text's horizontal alignment ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Swift you would use the UIKit classes instead of CoreText:

```
    let paragraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
    paragraphStyle.alignment = .center
    let attributes = [NSParagraphStyleAttributeName: paragraphStyle, NSForegroundColorAttributeName : UIColor.gray, NSFontAttributeName : UIFont(name: "Helvetica", size: 18)!]
    let attributedString = NSAttributedString(string: "some text", attributes: attributes)
```

I'm not a Xamarin programmer and my c# is rusty but Xamarin has the [equivalent functions](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/UIKit.NSMutableParagraphStyle/).

Comment: Thanks ! If someone's looking for the same thing, in Xamarin syntax : `var attributes = new UIStringAttributes() { };var paragraphStyle = new NSMutableParagraphStyle() { };
   paragraphStyle.Alignment = UITextAlignment.Center;
   attributes.ParagraphStyle = paragraphStyle;`